# Is it possible to auto-select a file for uploader in HTML/PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, sql

I am developing a Library Management System. An admin side is allowed to enter a new book. I am wondering if it is possible to auto-select a file to upload if the admin leaves it empty?

I used the following html code (among other input) for the form.

```
<input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="102400" type="hidden">
<input name="image" accept="image/jpeg" type="file">
```

In the php file that processes the input, I used the following code to upload the file.

```
$fileName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['image']['type'];

$filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;

$result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);
if (!$result) {
echo "Error uploading file";
exit;
}

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    $filePath = addslashes($filePath);
}
```

The code works perfectly fine. I am just wondering if there is a way to auto-select a default image if the admin leaves the file uploader empty. The image (containing the text "IMAGE NOT AVAILABLE") is already pre-saved on the folder where all uploaded images are saved. How do I select this before saving it to my database?

CHEERS!

Comment: Normally you would not upload the image for "not available" over and over again. What would you do if you ever want to change it? A waste of resources. Just leave the field null. Check the existence of the image when you want it to be displayed, and when there is no image use a default "not-available.jpg" or what so ever. This image should exisit one time only.

Comment: I may appreciate the @NicoO answer he's right instead of uploading the image not available you can directly show the image within your web if the data contains null value within database

Comment: @NicoO I don't plan on uploading the "not available" image repeatedly. I just want to select it for when the record needs it.

Comment: I see, sorry i got you wrong. Anyways, you should check if an image for the record [exists or not](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php).  When there is no image, switch the file name to the desired "not-exists.jpg" file.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if file uploaded to server using [`is_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) function.
If not, just save the path of your default `no-image.gif` or something similar.